# Annotate at the top of a marker with varying sizes in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Can I get the coordinates of markers to move the annotation to the top of the triangle?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [1,2,3,4,5]
Y = [1,1,1,1,1]
labels = 'ABCDE'
sizes = [1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(X, Y, s= sizes, marker = 10)

for x, y, label, size in zip(X, Y, labels, sizes):
    print(x,y)
    ax.annotate(label, (x, y), fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

Which gives me:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to (a) move the y coordinate by something proportional to the height of the marker; (b) root the text at bottom centre ("center" in American!).

Note that the "size" of a marker is proportional to its AREA. So its height is proportional to sqrt(size).

A certain amount of trial and error produced this. The height scaling probably depends on the type of marker.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [1,2,3,4,5]
Y = [1,1,1,1,1]
labels = 'ABCDE'
sizes = [1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(X, Y, s= sizes, marker = 10)

for x, y, label, size in zip(X, Y, labels, sizes):
    print(x,y,size)
    ax.annotate(label, (x, y + math.sqrt( size ) / 3000 ), horizontalalignment='center', fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! No way to get the coordinates, right?

Comment: The coordinates of the "bottom center" for the text box are `x, y + math.sqrt( size ) / 3000`. The height of a particular style of marker is proportional to sqrt(size), but I'm not sure where the specification for these heights is given - maybe a long delve into the matplotlib specification. If the marker style is changed then that 3000 may need adjusting.